# how to save "components" for re-use in blender

Tags: macos, components, blender, reusability

I am learning blender 2.8 on a mac.  Here's a question I'm sure is answered, but I don't seem to have quite the right kws to google...

I am building a 3d house, an it seems like I should be able to save a certain unit of work, let's say a "board" which is a 6'x7'x.5" mesh cube, and name it "board", and save it under that name.  Then I can, whenever I need to, spawn as many "boards" as I need and snap them together, loop cut them etc.

The purposes of this would be (1) time savings (2) making sure that I'm starting from a pre-set standard, so that I don't run the risk of mis-drawing something when I repeatedly create or copy it.  Ideally I'd like to be able to port such items in a component library from one project to the next.

How to I save these named "components" and re-use them?  What are the keywords I should use for this concept?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an option like that, but here is an alternative-
In the outliner (present at the top right), duplicate the board and save there. Do not make any changes to it, and duplicate it whenever you need to use it.
As for the 'snapping', you can use the Array modifier, which can spawn the same object in a series
This might be helpful- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html

Comment: Thanks I will try that.